# Prevent Clojure from simplifying ratios

Tags: clojure

Is there any way to prevent clojure from making for example a 2/5 from 6/15? I need for a function to have the original denominators of ratios, hence the question.

Comment: A ratio is not two integers, but rather **one rational number**. It's not supposed to store the information that you want from it.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to prevent clojure from making 2/5 from 6/15. This is most readily apparent from the equality of `clojure.lang.Ratio` defined [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Ratio.java#L28). Preserving the original unreduced version would break equality.

This sounds like a datatype problem. You are putting information into a type that doesn't preserve the amount of data that you need. Fundamentally you are putting two numbers into a ratio datatype which is a single scalar value. You'll (most probably) need to thread more information through or delay the conversion into a ratio.

Answer (score 3):

The calculation of GCD is not conditional:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Numbers.java#L355

You can create a clojure.lang.Ratio type directly:

```
user=> (def x (clojure.lang.Ratio. 
  (java.math.BigInteger. "6") (java.math.BigInteger. "15")))
user=> (type x)
clojure.lang.Ratio
user=> x
6/15
```

But compareTo assumes the reduction has occurred and checks the numerator and denominator values individually:

```
user=> (def y (/ 6 15))
#'user/y
user=> (type y)
clojure.lang.Ratio
user=> y
2/5
user=> (= x y)
false
```

And other operations will wind up reducing:

```
user=> (* 3 x)
6/5
user=> (* 3 y)
6/5
```

Comment: Although it's a bit hokey you can force the reduction, and make the comparison work correctly, by the simple expedient of multiplying by 1, e.g. `(= (* x 1) y)` returns `true` given `x` and `y` as defined above..

Answer (score 3):

Strange requirement. A simple solution is NOT to calculate, i.e. store them as is

```
  {:n 6 :d 15}
```

The only time you calculate is at the end, when you want a result, or if you want to check for equal.

Comment: How can i NOT calculate, when the inputs from end users are going to be in form of ratios? It makes a difference to write some ratios down as argument or many pairs of hash-maps!

Comment: @amirteymuri they're easy to transform, so no, there isn't a big difference. If you don't like a hashmap, you can use vectors, like `[6 15]`.

Comment: "inputs from end users are going to be in form of ratios" - don't you mean input from the users are going to be in the form of strings formatted as ratios? If yes, then I don't see a difference: you have to transform it anyway.